# HTML Video настроить

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, видео

Здравствуйте, есть у меня вот такая разметка

```
<div class="sect5__items">
                                <div class="sect5__items_item">
                                    <video src="video/video.mp4"></video>
                                    <div class="play"></div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="sect5__items_item">
                                    <video src="video/video.mp4"></video>
                                    <div class="play"></div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="sect5__items_item">
                                    <video src="video/video.mp4"></video>
                                    <div class="play"></div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="sect5__items_item">
                                    <video src="video/video.mp4"></video>
                                    <div class="play"></div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="sect5__items_item">
                                    <video src="video/video.mp4"></video>
                                    <div class="play"></div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="sect5__items_item">
                                    <video src="video/video.mp4"  controls></video>
                                    <div class="play"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

И такой jQuery код

```
var controls = {
        video: $("video"),
        playpause: $(".play")                 
    };

    var video = controls.video[0];
    controls.playpause.click(function(){
        if (video.paused) {
            video.play();
            $('.play').css('opacity', '0');
        } else {
            video.pause();
        }   
        $(this).toggleClass("paused"); 
    });
```

В данном варианте, при нажатии на любое видео открывается только первое видео и сколько я не пробовал вариантов, ничего у меня не получилось, а надо бы, чтобы при нажатии на play открывалось видео только этого родителя, а не других или как в даннном случае только первого. Может можно как-то эту проблему решить?

Comment: не вижу в вашем примере вообще никакого выбора контейнера который должен открыватся.

Comment: @Insider Прощу прощение, исправил код

Comment: Все равно не видно выбор какой контейнер нужно открыть. У вас не хватает элементов `hide` на каждый `div`, так же, не хватает кнопки для открытия того или иного `div'a`. Ваш скрипт не знает какой из элементов открыть/закрыть/показать и тд.

Comment: Все там есть, просто при нажатии на кнопку .play открывается видео в его родителе.

Comment: @LiEm, вы же сами достали первоё видео и запускаете его: var video = controls.video[0];

Comment: @Horchynskyi Вы правы, а как я могу убрать данную выборку и сделать, чтобы видео открывалось в зависимости от родителя?

Comment: @LiEm, немного запутался в вашем коде, video.paused - это проверка на класс?

Comment: @Horchynskyi Там выходит если было нажатие на функцию паузы, то есть как бы видео снялось с нее, то мы запускаем видео и прячем кнопку .play  а если же нет то ставим Видео на паузу

Comment: @Horchynsky думаю идет проверка на паузе видео или нет

Comment: Хорошо, по Вашему тут все есть :). Тогда объясните мне, как скипт должен понять при нажатии на кнопку play, какие видео запустить?

Comment: @LiEm, и кстати как потом кнопка появлятся то должна обратно?
Просто невидимость 0 у неё становится. скрипт вроде как сделал но с кнопкой не понял)

Comment: @Horchynskyi после нажатия на кнопку, она больше никогда не появляется, просто покаывается до первого нажатия

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавил всем кнопкам изначальный класс paused для удобства
Реализация простая и подойдет только по указанной вами html разметке

```js
var controls = {
        video: $("video"),
        playpause: $(".play")                 
    };
    //Клик на playpause
    controls.playpause.on('click', function(){
        //Проверка класса кнопки
        if ($(this).hasClass("paused")) {
            //Делаем эту кнопку невидимой
            $(this).css('opacity', '0');
            //Находим соседа кнопки который в верху (в нашем случае video) и включаем (get(0) необзодим т.к. play() не является функцией jquery, get(0) вернет чистый html документ
            $(this).prev().get(0).play();
            $(this).toggleClass("paused"); 
        }
    });
    controls.video.on('click', function(){
        $(this).next().css('opacity', '1');
        $(this).next().toggleClass("paused");
        $(this).removeAttr("controls", "0");
        $(this).get(0).pause();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sect5__items">
    <div class="sect5__items_item">
        <video src="test.mp4"></video>
        <div class="play paused">test play</div>
    </div>

    <div class="sect5__items_item">
        <video src="video/video.mp4"></video>
        <div class="play paused"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="sect5__items_item">
        <video src="video/video.mp4"></video>
        <div class="play paused"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="sect5__items_item">
        <video src="video/video.mp4"></video>
        <div class="play paused"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="sect5__items_item">
        <video src="video/video.mp4"></video>
        <div class="play paused"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="sect5__items_item">
        <video src="video/video.mp4"  controls></video>
        <div class="play paused"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: К сожалению не хочет работать при нажатии на кнопку play, надо изначально кликнуть на область видео вне зоны кнопки play, а потом уже можно нажимать на нее и она будет работать.

Comment: @LiEm, я у себя тестировал с первого раза запускало, возможно у вас какой-то элемент там перекрывает? добавили кнопкам изначальный дополнительный класс "paused"?

Comment: Огромное спасибо, начало работать, наверное кэш у меня мусором был забит

Comment: Еще вот мне нужно чтобы при нажатии на .play атрибут controls добавлялся к тегу video. А при повторном нажатии убирался

Comment: Я пробовал сделать так  $('video').attr("controls", "0");  но здесь естественно при клике на видео данный атрибут добавлялся ко всем существующим видео, а надо, чтобы только к тому на которое было совершено нажатие

Comment: Надеюсь Вы сможете мне еще в этом помочь?

Comment: @LiEm, надо использовать $(this).prev().attr("controls", "0"); 
Сотрите: $(this) берет элемент кнопки на которую кликнули
.prev() - находит элемент  который прописан перед кликнутым элементом (кнопкой, и получаем видео). Если вы указываете $('video') - скрипт берет все элементы с тегом видео. а в моём варианте мы явно указиваем - добавь атрибут только такому-то видео.В нашем случае такому, которое вверху перед кнопкой)

Comment: Спасибо, теперь дейсвительно работает, но вот пробовал удалить данный атрибут при повторном нажатии таким способом и он не удаляется почему-то что не правильно?  $(this).prev().removeAttr("controls", "0");

Comment: @LiEm, нажатие на кнопку?

Comment: Получается я нажимаю на кнопку .play и видео воспроизводиться атрибут .controls добавляется к тегу video, но вот теперь я кликаю второй раз по области видео, видео останавливается, кнопка .play появляется, но атрибут controls не убирается

Comment: @LiEm, клик срабатывает уже непоседственно на video так что вам не надо искать предидущий элемент.
надо использовать просто $(this).removeAttr("controls", "0"); 
$(this) - то на что кникнули

Comment: ахаха ну так то да, я очень рад что вы зашли в переписку и мне помогли, еще раз огромное спасибо!!!